# Prediction Interval , Confidence Interval , Standard error

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, prediction-interval

What is the relation between Confidence Interval and prediction interval and,  standard error for a point estimate? Please explain with an example.

As per my understanding, the standard error is a variation of point estimate (of a parameter) around the average estimation of the point estimate.

This standard error is accounted in confidence intervals.

And Prediction interval carries many such confidence intervals.

Answer (score 6):

A [prediction interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) is an interval that covers the future (or otherwise unknown) value of a random variable with some prespecified probability.

Prediction intervals are conceptually related to [confidence intervals](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/confidence-interval/info), but they are not the same.  A prediction interval pertains to a *realization* (which has not yet been observed, but *will* be observed in the future), whereas a confidence interval pertains to a *parameter* (which is *in principle* not observable, e.g., the population mean).

In the time series context, prediction intervals are known as forecast intervals.

*(This is copied verbatim from [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) for the [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval) tag.)*

---

The standard error is the estimated standard deviation of an estimate of a parameter. It is typically used to construct a [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval) for the parameter, together with the point estimate and usually a normal distribution, which is motivated by the Central Limit Theorem or similar.

---

As an example, let us simulate some weakly related data and fit a (correctly specified) model. In R:

```
set.seed(1)
nn <- 20
predictor <- runif(nn)
response <- 3*predictor+rnorm(nn)

model <- lm(response~predictor)
xx <- seq(min(predictor),max(predictor),by=.01)

plot(predictor,response,pch=19)
lines(xx,predict(model,newdata=data.frame(predictor=xx)))
)
```

[image: scatterplot]

We can now extract the quantities we are interested in:

- The *standard error* of (say) the parameter estimate for the regression slope is 0.7394:

  ```
  > summary(model)

  ... truncated ...

  Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
  (Intercept)   0.9412     0.4593   2.049   0.0553 .
  predictor     1.4083     0.7394   1.905   0.0729 .
  ```
- This allows us to obtain a symmetric 95% *confidence interval* for the regression slope parameter of $[-0.14,2.96]$:

  ```
  > confint(model)
                    2.5 %   97.5 %
  (Intercept) -0.02380633 1.906270
  predictor   -0.14499836 2.961647
  ```
- Finally, we can get a 95% *prediction interval* for a new observation. For that we need to specify at what value of the predictor we want to calculate this PI. For instance, we could use a predictor value of $0.5$, yielding a PI of $[-0.34,3.63]$:

  ```
  > predict(model,newdata=data.frame(predictor=0.5),interval="prediction")
         fit        lwr      upr
  1 1.645394 -0.3415354 3.632323
  ```

We see how the standard error and the confidence interval pertain to *unobservable parameters*, while the prediction interval pertains to (yet unseen) *observations*.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen.  Could you please quote a single example explaining all the three terms ?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks. It is an amazing explanation.