# Why is the noise included in the posterior predictive distribution in bayesian regression?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, predictive-models, posterior

Assume the following model: $y = b_0 + b_1 * x$ where we set some priors to $b_0, b_1$.

Let $I$ denote our historical data and $x^*$ denote future inputs.

Let $p(b_0, b_1|I)$ denote our posteriors.

We can then define the posterior predictive distribution as $p(y^*|I, x^*) = \int p(y^*|b_0, b_1, x^*)p(b_0, b_1|I)$.

Now my question is, why do we also sample the noise in the likelihood term $p(y^*|b_0, b_1, x^*)$ and not just disregard it and just use the posterior samples to compute the desired quantity? Does this procedure have a name?

Comment: totally; this situation is analogous to the difference between computing a confidence interval on the mean and a prediction interval in frequentist stats.

Comment: interesting, would you mind writing a full answer, what is the reason for including the noise term?

Comment: may be useful to check answers for the frequentist version of your question, as the reasoning is identical; e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415674/prediction-interval-confidence-interval-standard-error

Comment: got it now, would have accepted this as an answer.

Comment: feel free to summarize what you've learned as an answer.

Comment: @JohnMadden i assume this is correct: the difference is that the posterior predictive distribution literally consider new values of $y^*$ therefore it also makes sense to include the noise term. Disregarding the noise term but having the same expression would essentially mean that we predict a range for the mean response, not an actually new value $y^*$. Now notice, if you just want a prediction of the mean and no intervals, you can use either one since both will be centered around the same mean.

Comment: yes that sounds exactly right to me